# Responsive meteogram (icons) highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I did responsive  Meteogram , but when the browser window is enlarged, the icons ( clouds, sun ) don't move. How to get around this ?

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/fsrqvn9f/2/][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't telling the chart to move those items.  You'll need to add a handler for the chart redraw event:

```
   chart: {
        renderTo: this.container,
        marginBottom: 70,
        marginRight: 40,
        marginTop: 50,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                // remove chart annotations
                meteogram.onChartLoad(meteogram.chart);
            }
        }
    },
```

I didn't write the code to remove the annotations, but you'll need to implement that also.  I'd reccommend adding them to a group, so you can remove them all at once.

http://jsfiddle.net/fsrqvn9f/4/

EDIT - Removing the icons.

Here's what you would do to remove the weather icons.  You'll need to do something similar for the Wind arrows.

When you add the icons to the graph, add them in a named group.  In this case I named the group weatherSymbols.  highcharts will create you elements with the class highcharts-weatherSymbols (or 'highcharts-' + grouname). This way you can easily find these items to remove them later.:

```
        // Create a group element that is positioned and clipped at 30 pixels width and height
        group = chart.renderer.g('weatherSymbols')
            .attr({
                translateX: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 15,
                translateY: point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 30,
                zIndex: 5
            })
```

Then removing them is as easy as:

```
    events: {
        redraw: function () {
            // remove chart annotations
            $('.highcharts-weatherSymbols').remove();
            meteogram.onChartLoad(meteogram.chart);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you help me write ' code to remove the annotations '. I have no idea how to do it..

Comment: @Sebastiano I've added the basics to get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. With the wind I tried this:

`arrow = chart.renderer.g('WindSymbols').path(
                            meteogram.windArrow(meteogram.windSpeedNames[i])
                        )
                            .attr({
                                rotation: parseInt(meteogram.windDirections[i], 10),
                                translateX: x, // rotation center
                                translateY: y // rotation center
                            });
                    }`

Comment: `events: { redraw: function () { // remove chart annotations $('.highcharts-WindSymbols').remove(); $('.highcharts-weatherSymbols').remove(); meteogram.onChartLoad(meteogram.chart); } }` But this does not work in this case..Help.

Comment: @Sebastiano do you have a fiddle with your changes?  What doesn't work?  Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Clouds work, but all the time there is a problem with the arrows: jsfiddle.net/fsrqvn9f/6    Help.

Comment: it probably is not as easy as with the symbols of the clouds. Can you help me with this also ?